# Adding a helper method with a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have found a lot of information about adding form helper methods (see one of my other questions), but I can't find anything about adding helper methods as if they were defined in `application_helper.rb`.

I've tried copying `application_helper.rb` from a rails app into the gem but that didn't work.

I've also tried:

```
class ActionView::Helpers
```

..but that produces an error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a module somewhere for your helper methods:

```
module MyHelper
  def mymethod
  end
end
```

Mix it into ActionView::Base (such as in `init.rb` or `lib/your_lib_file.rb`)

```
ActionView::Base.send :include, MyHelper
```

Comment: According to @BrandonTilley comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791211/how-do-i-extract-rails-view-helpers-into-a-gem#comment-42572499) you should use `ActiveSupport.on_load( :action_view ){ include MyGem::ViewHelpers }` instead of `send :include` as of ActiveSupport 3.0.0. More details in linked SO thread.

Answer (score 3):

To extends @sdbrown's excellent Answer to Rails 4:

```
# in in lib/my_rails_engine.rb
require 'my_rails_engine/my_rails_helper.rb'
require 'my_rails_engine/engine.rb'
```

And

```
# in lib/my_rails_engine/engine.rb
module MyRailsEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer "my_rails_engine.engine" do |app|
      ActionView::Base.send :include, MyRailsEngine::MyRailsHelpers
    end
  end
end
```

and finally

```
# in lib/my_rails_engine/my_rails_helper.rb 
module MyRailsEngine
  module MyRailsHelpers
    # ...
    def your_helper_here
    end
  end
end
```