# How do I extract Rails view helpers into a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, actionview

I have a set of rails view helpers that I use regularly, and would like to package them up into a gem, such that I could just put a line in my Gemfile, and have the helpers accessible from my views.

I have created gems before using Bundler, and Jeweler, however, I'm not all all clear on how to organize the Rails view helpers in a gem, and include them into rails.

I would appreciate any pointers, or links to up-to-date tutorials on how to do this for Rails 3

Thanks

Just to clarify:  The question isn't on "how to create a gem".  Its "how to package view helpers in a gem, so I can use them in Rails"

Edit 2:
I also agree with the poster below..  A rails engine is waay too much overkill for this kind of (hopefully simple) requirement

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In my opinion, a full [Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791211/how-do-i-extract-rails-view-helpers-into-a-gem/5795563#5795563) is overkill for this task. You could instead just create a [Railtie](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) which includes your helpers into ActionView::Base when it initializes.

```
# lib/my_gem/view_helpers.rb
module MyGem
  module ViewHelpers
    def pre(text)
      content_tag :pre, text
    end

    def another_helper
      # super secret stuff
    end
  end
end

# lib/my_gem/railtie.rb
require 'my_gem/view_helpers'
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "my_gem.view_helpers" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) { include MyGem::ViewHelpers }
    end
  end
end

# lib/my_gem.rb
require 'my_gem/railtie' if defined?(Rails)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this.. will report back

Comment: Hi, I want to know: why it named "Railtie", what does "Railtie" mean ?

Comment: @why Well, I don't know for sure, but I assume it's because it's the class with the hooks necessary to "tie" the code into "Rails"

Comment: @why "Railties" are the wood slats that train rails are secured to, i.e. that "tie" them together. It's just a cutesy way to name a similar construct in RoR that is in keeping with the "rails" theme.

Comment: @BrandonTilley if I could offer one recommendation, it would be to utilize the built-in load hook capabilities instead of calling the private method `include` on `ActionView::Base`. Rails has offered lazy load hooks as a part of ActiveSupport since [3.0.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb). Thus, the alternate code for the initializer block would look like `ActiveSupport.on_load( :action_view ){ include MyGem::ViewHelpers }`

Answer (score 5):

Also if you want include helper only for Rails3 version you can use

```
# lib/my_gem.rb
require 'my_gem/railtie' if defined?(Rails::Railtie)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably looking for is an [engine](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).  An engine is a gem that contains rails application pieces (in fact, a rails application is itself an engine.)