# How do I make functions in a gem available to Sinatra views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sinatra

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791211) asks how to extract Rails view helper functions into a gem, and the accept answer is pretty good.

I am wondering - how to do the same for Sinatra? I'm making a gem that has a bunch of helper functions defined in a module, and I'd like to make these functions available to Sinatra views. But whatever I try, I cannot seem to access the functions, I just get a `undefined local variable or method` error.

So far, my gem structure looks like this (other stuff like gemspec omitted):

```
cool_gem/
  lib/
    cool_gem/
      helper_functions.rb
      sinatra.rb 
  cool_gem.rb
```

In `cool_gem.rb`, I have:

```
if defined?(Sinatra) and Sinatra.respond_to? :register
  require 'cool_gem/sinatra'
end
```

In `helper_functions.rb`, I have:

```
module CoolGem
  module HelperFunctions

    def heading_tag(text)
      "<h1>#{text}</h1>"
    end

    # + many more functions
  end
end
```

In `sinatra.rb`, I have:

```
require 'cool_gem/helper_functions'

module CoolGem
  module Sinatra

    module MyHelpers
      include CoolGem::HelperFunctions
    end

    def self.registered(app)
      app.helpers MyHelpers
    end

  end
end
```

This doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

(And in case you're wondering, yes, I need the helper functions in a separate file. I plan to make the gem compatible with Rails as well, so I want to keep the functions isolated/de-coupled if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re mainly just missing the call to `Sinatra.register` (in `cool_gem/sinatra.rb`):

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'cool_gem/helper_functions'

module CoolGem
  # you could just put this directly in the CoolGem module if you wanted,
  # rather than have a Sinatra sub-module
  module Sinatra

    def self.registered(app)
      #no need to create another module here
      app.helpers CoolGem::HelperFunctions
    end

  end
end

# this is what you're missing:
Sinatra.register CoolGem::Sinatra
```

Now any classic style Sinatra app that requires `cool_gem` will have the helpers available. If you use the modular style you’ll also need to call `register CoolGem::Sinatra` inside the `Sinatra::Base` subclass.

In this case, if you are just providing some helper methods, an easier way might be to just use the `helpers` method (again in `cool_gem/sinatra.rb`):

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'cool_gem/helper_functions'

Sinatra.helpers CoolGem::HelperFunctions
```

Now the methods will be available in classic style apps, and modular style apps will need to call `helpers CoolGem::HelperFunctions`. This is a bit simpler, but if you are adding methods to the DSL context you will need to use `registered` as above.

Comment: Thanks. But I found that I did not need `require 'sinatra/base` in `sinatra.rb`, nor did I need `Sinatra.register CoolGem::Sinatra`. Just adding `register CoolGem::Sinatra` to my application's class seems to be all that was needed...

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- Yes, if you have already required sinatra (e.g. in your main app) you won’t need to again. Also `Sinatra.register CoolGem::Sinatra` will make the extensions available in classic Sinatra apps. If you are using modular style you’ll need to use `register` in your apps class as well. If you are making the gem available you might want to include `Sinatra.register CoolGem::Sinatra` so that it will work as expected for people using the classic style.